# Writing a short paper focusing on recent advancements in a specific field

Tags: publications, writing, literature-review

Is this an acceptable and common approach to write a short paper (maybe a letter) on a relatively broad topic (e.g. applications of deep learning in a specific field) with the aim of reporting recent advancements and summarizing reported performance?
If it's OK, please provide an example (link or title of the paper) which is published in a prestigious journal/magazine.

Comment: If you're unsure, I suspect you're not a senior researcher with a decade or two of experience in the field. Are you the right person to summarize recent advancements then?

Comment: I agree, typically this type of papers should be written by very senior researchers (such as an emeritus) and possibly as more of an editorial or opinion piece. If you need examples, search in your favourite literature database. I did a quick search in Web of Science and had many hits searching for "recent advances" in the title. Many of these were in low-impact journals but you find such articles in all journals. In my quick search I even found one Nature editorial (from 1948!). If you plan to write such a paper, I suggest that you first ask the editor of the journal you plan to submit to ...

Comment: @Roland  Thanks for the comments. I think there is need to more clarification. I do not mean write a critical survey or something like that. I think about summarizing 40 papers with focus on using deep learning for a specific purpose. In fact, I want only to provide a high level overview of how different deep learning algorithms are used for that purpose.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, a short letter or editorial that surveys literature in the way you described would probably only be accepted from a relatively senior scholar with an established reputation. Note, though, that such a submission would not (or should not) be considered a peer-reviewed contribution--it would only be an opinion piece. If you do not have such reputation, then you would probably need to write a regular-length survey paper and submit it to the regular peer review process so that its quality can be evaluated by experts (that is, not by just the journal editors). Perhaps what I have described here is somewhat idealistic, but I think that is how things often work in journals with rigorous and relatively objective processes.

Without knowing if you are a senior or junior scholar, and without knowing your discipline, it is not easy to provide the kinds of examples that you asked for.